Remove unused css in wp-rocket not working
I'm using wp-rocket for my WordPress website and I applied the Remove unused css option but it seems not working, and still shows in PageSpeed Insight that I have to remove unused css, what should I do??
Another thing is that performance on desktop is above 90% and not on mobile.

Does "remove unused CSS" remove any CSS? If so, it is working, it just can't tell what is or isn't used for some reason. That feature may or may not contribute to your score in various tools such as PageSpeed.

It is not removing any css @ChrisHaas

Which hosting service are you using? Sometimes the hosting service has some services which creates conflicts with WP Rocket and does not allow it perform all tasks.
